# best way to handle authentication in single page application ( SPA)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, laravel-4

In single page application usually we request a web page (dashboard.html) and we get it from server and then we are rendering some dashboard data on it (using ajax)

I want to display dashboard.html only when user is authenticated from backed (have valid email and password) otherwise I want to redirect him to login page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dashbaard.json",
    dataType: "json"
}).done( function(data){
    // data = { inValid: true } - from backend
    if(data.inValid){
        alert("You are not authorized user, please register 1st!");
        location.href = "register.html";
    } else {
        // render data on dashboard page - valid user
    }
})
```

but here is a problem suppose user is not valid

- user requested the dashboard.html, all assets (css, js, images) would be loaded  although user is not valid, in this case we have no point to load single css or js file

Expected result: user requested dashboard.html if user is not valid he should be redirected to login/register page immediately without loading anything un-necessarly from server.

How we handle it with single page application ( no page refresh if possible) i need best possible solution without page flicker,  I am using Laravel 4 for handling back-end authentication that does it's job very well.

Comment: How are you handling the routing? And the templating?

Comment: You could pass in a var the the template in your view, maybe a md5 of the user id? Then check against it when doing gets/posts with ajax.

Comment: Was "dashbaard" a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Change dashboard.html to another server language, like php, asp.net etc, and handle authentication at server side. Redirected to login page if invalid.
2. Request authentication on page ready, and add beforeSend setting on per ajax request. `$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function(){ // request authentication sync and redirect }});`

If you take No.2 method, you'd better add the authorize method to a javascript file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Teddy for your feedback on this, here I am talking about SPA so I can't change dashbard.html to dashboard.php, I want complete separation of concern that's the point of SPA backend developer should be responsible for sending data( JSON) to front end not for creating html so #1 not feasible option for me.

#2 is not valid because you can not validate user on client side without backend help ( email, password in db should be validated) 

I already explained the possible way in js code but that's not the optimal, need something better solution

Answer (score 0):

My way is using a popup/modal login box for handling this situation
If the ajax request return unauthenticated user then show login box (facebox, bootstrap modal, anything)
If the ajax request return authenticated user (along with data) then render dashboard data